# how to use boto3 Filters for boolean value

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I'm using boto 3 in python 3.5.2 trying to describe ec2 images.  The doc says one of the available filters is 'is-public':

```
is-public - A Boolean that indicates whether the image is public.
```

But the Filter syntax wants a list of strings - and only a list of strings - for the Value.  If I try passing a Boolean, it gives me a type error:

```
Invalid type for parameter Filters[0].Values[0], value: False, type: <class 'bool'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

My code:

```
  response = session.client("ec2").describe_images(
Filters=[
  {'Name': 'is-public',
   'Values': [False],
  },
```

How do I pass a Boolean filter when it will only accept a string?

Thanks...
Bill

Answer (score 3):

This works for me... use lower case.

```
    ami_filter = [{"Name": "platform", 'Values': ["windows"]}, 
        {"Name": "virtualization-type", 'Values': ["hvm"]}, 
        {"Name": "image-type", 'Values': ["machine"]},
        {"Name": "architecture", 'Values': ["x86_64"]},
        {"Name": "state", 'Values': ["available"]},
        {"Name": "is-public", 'Values': ['false']}]

    ami_owners = ['amazon']
    results = client.describe_images(Filters=ami_filter, Owners=ami_owners)
```

Comment: Ah, but now you're supplying a string - 'false' - to the filter, not a Boolean value, and the string 'false' does NOT match the Boolean False.

Comment: lower case within quotes actually works